# Can I provide custom serialization for XmlSerializer without implementing IXmlSerializable?

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

We're using `XmlSerializer`, and I want to provide custom serialization for certain classes. However, I don't always have the ability to modify the source code of the class in question, otherwise I could just make it implement `IXmlSerializable`. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I know you can adorn the classes with various XmlAttributes (like `XmlElement`, `XmlArray`, etc), but you're asking specifically about how to control the XML output of non-modifiable classes?

Comment: I use "proxy" classes that impliment IXmlSerializable with the given root tag name and use the ReadXml function to construct the real underlying value, which is then exposed in a public property.

Comment: Well there's this [constructor overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/65k4wece.aspx) which lets you override the attributes used on the types, but I don't know if it lets you alter the behaviour/result of `IXmlSerializable.ReadXml`. EDIT: Can you separate the serialization concerns between your business objects and the 3rd party objects?

Comment: @Chris. Yes - I want to control the Xml output of non-modifiable classes. Specifically, the non-modifiable classes don't permit the default serialization, in that they have some properties with private setters, etc.

Comment: @asawyer. That could work. If I serialize a top level object of type X that has property of type "problem" class Y, how would I go about using a proxy for Y?

Comment: @Rob I'll write up an example please give me a few minutes.

Comment: @Rob I dont know if its the solution you need, but I wrote up a working example for you.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's a simple example of the proxy deserialize helper:

Given a type that we cannot directly control serialization of at the class level:

```
public sealed class Class //contrived example
{
    public string Property {get;set;}
}
```

And the xml we need to deserialize with:

```
<Class>
  <Property>Value</Property>
</Class>
```

You could create a proxy type to manually process the deserialization process of the target type like so:

```
[XmlRoot("Class")] // <-- Very important
public sealed class ClassSerializerProxy : IXmlSerializable
{
    public Class ClassValue {get;set;}

    public System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema GetSchema(){return null;}
    public void WriteXml(System.Xml.XmlWriter writer){}

    public void ReadXml(System.Xml.XmlReader reader)
    {
        var x = XElement.ReadFrom(reader) as XElement;
        this.ClassValue = new Class();
        //again this is a simple contrived example
        this.ClassValue.Property = x.XPathSelectElement("Property").Value;
    }
}
```

Usage is:

```
void Main()
{
    // get the xml value somehow
    var xdoc= XDocument.Parse(@"<Class><Property>Value</Property></Class>");

    // deserialize the xml into the proxy type
    var proxy = Deserialize<ClassSerializerProxy>(xdoc);

    // read the resulting value
    var value = proxy.ClassValue;
}

public object Deserialize(XDocument xmlDocument, Type DeserializeToType)
{
    XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(DeserializeToType);
    using (XmlReader reader = xmlDocument.CreateReader())
        return xmlSerializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

Now throw in some generics and an extension method, and we can clean the call site up a bit for a final (EXCEPT EXCEPTION HANDLING) version:

Usage:

```
void Main()
{
    var xml = @"<Class><Property>Value</Property></Class>";

    var value = xml.DeserializeWithProxy<ClassSerializerProxy,Class>();

    value.Dump();
}
```

Your instance type:

```
public sealed class Class
{
    public string Property {get;set;}
}
```

An interface that proxy types must implement

```
public interface ISerializerProxy<TInstanceType> where TInstanceType : class
{
    TInstanceType Value { get; }
}
```

The example proxy now implements the new interface

```
[XmlRoot("Class")]
public sealed class ClassSerializerProxy : IXmlSerializable, ISerializerProxy<Class>
{
    public Class Value {get;set;}

    public System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema GetSchema(){return null;}
    public void WriteXml(System.Xml.XmlWriter writer){}

    public void ReadXml(System.Xml.XmlReader reader)
    {
        var x = XElement.ReadFrom(reader) as XElement;
        this.Value = new Class();
        this.Value.Property = x.XPathSelectElement("Property").Value;
    }
}
```

The deserialization method is now an extension method on `string` and can be used with any proxy type.

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static TInstanceType DeserializeWithProxy<TProxyType,TInstanceType>(this string xml) 
        where TProxyType : ISerializerProxy<TInstanceType> 
        where TInstanceType : class
    {
        using (XmlReader reader = XDocument.Parse(xml).CreateReader())
        {
            var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TProxyType));
            return (xmlSerializer.Deserialize(reader) as ISerializerProxy<TInstanceType>).Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to use this approach if I have a large object tree, and want to use the default serialization for the tree as a whole, but custom serialization for certain leaves? If I have access to the source, I can make those leaves implement IXmlSerializable, and put custom serialization there. But if I can't modify the leaves, do I need to write serialization code for the entire tree? Or can I just target the small subset of problem classes somehow?

Comment: @asawyer This is a great answer!  I chose to also implement the WriteXml functionality since my real class is not XML serializable in itself.  It consists of a bunch of read-only accessors which can only be set through the constructor.

Comment: @natephette I'm so happy I was able to help!

Comment: @asawyer I'd be interested in knowing if what Rob asked is possible with this code.

Comment: @TheMuffinMan I don't know honestly. It sounds plausible enough. If I had that sort of need I'd give it a shot. Perhaps asking a new question may help?

Comment: @asawyer The question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44290214/contract-first-wcf-soap-development-controlling-over-primitive-types-xml-serial