# Deserialize XML to derived class with same element name?

Tags: c#, xml, inheritance, asp.net-web-api, deserialization

I have XML in a format like so:

```
<TaskList>
<Task type="TaskA"/>
<Task type="TaskB"/>
</TaskList>
```

that I am trying to deserialize into classes like so:

```
public class TaskList
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Task", Type = typeof(Task))]
    public Task[] Task { get; set; } 
}

[XmlInclude(typeof(TaskA))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(TaskB))]
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Task")]
public class Task
{
    //Common Fields
}

public class TaskA : Task
{
    //Specific stuff
}

public class TaskB : Task
{
    //Specific stuff
}
```

Trying to deserialize it:

```
TaskList taskList = (TaskList)new XmlSerializer(typeof(TaskList)).Deserialize(new StringReader(xmlString));
```

In this configuration it'll give me all of the tasks as the base type "Task". How can I get it to use the derived classes?

Comment: Interesting question.  As far as I know, you will not get this functionality out of the box with the XmlSerializer class.  You will need to extend the functionality of the XmlSerializer in a custom class in order to instantiate the correct derived type based on the `type` node attribute.  Maybe someone else will get to it before I do, but I'll work on a sample implementation.  This question is related and may have a useful answer to get you started: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17236823/can-i-provide-custom-serialization-for-xmlserializer-without-implementing-ixmlse

Comment: The type information is usually persisted within specialized namespace (declaration -xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance") xsi:type="TaskA" xsi:type="TaskB" should do the job. Have you tried opposite approach (serialize few dummy rows and see how the xml will look like ? )

Comment: @OndrejSvejdar I don't understand what you mean? Unfortunately I can't change the XML format coming in.

Comment: @xDaevax Thanks for the help. I've never done anything with the XmlSerializer besides its basic usage, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: @OndrejSvejdar  What flags need to be set on the XmlSerializer instance or on the classes being serialized to cause this behavior when serializing the type?  That is fantastic news!

Comment: @xDaevax - Shawn has it already there - it is the XmlInclude, unfortunately, he does not control the input xml.

Comment: Hacky as hell, but `xmlString = xmlString.Replace(" type=", " xsi:type=")` is probably the simplest solution for me right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `XmlSerializer` would be able to take types into account with your classes if the xml would look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<TaskList xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Task xsi:type="TaskA" />
  <Task xsi:type="TaskB" />
</TaskList>
```

Notice the type information is persisted within special namespace.
However as you can't control xml format, you'll have to implement `IXmlSerializable` on `TaskList` and do the dirty work yourself.

Personally as the xml is simple, I would use LinqToXml.

```
static Task TaskFromElement(XElement element) {
  switch (element.Attribute("type").Value) {
    case "TaskA":
      return new TaskA();
    case "TaskB":
      return new TaskB();
    default:
      throw new NotImplementedException();
  }
}

var doc = XDocument.Parse(@"<TaskList>
  <Task type=""TaskA""/>
  <Task type=""TaskB""/>
</TaskList>");
var tasks = from e in doc.Descendants("Task")
            select TaskFromElement(e);
var taskList = new TaskList { Task = tasks.ToArray() };
```

Comment: Unfortunately I simplified the xml an awful lot for this question (there are additional types under TaskList and everything has attributes) so I don't think LinqToXml is going to work here.