# returning NULL from an IEnumerable method if no results were found

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper, ienumerable

I am using Automapper and classes with Xml serialization to generate an XML file.

In this method, it returns an IEnumerable to Automapper, which then writes out a series of `<GenerationMethod>...</GenerationMethod>` XML elements.

It does work, however, if it returns an empty IEnumerable, because no results were found, I am getting empty XML tags like this:

```
<GenerationMethod />
```

Is there a way to return NULL so that empty XML tags are not generated?

Here is the method. Thanks!

```
public static IEnumerable<GenerationMethod> GetGenerationMethod(this DungeonGrid monster)
{

    var customMonster = monster.Stats
            .Where(e => e.Stat.Category.IsActive);

    if (monster.MonsterType.DestructionMethod.StartsWith("TEST"))
    {
        yield return new GenerationMethod(monster.MonsterType.DestructionMethod);
    }

    foreach (Stat in customMonster)
    {
        if (DungeonLookupByStatId.ContainsKey(customMonster.MonsterType.Id))
            yield return DungeonLookupByStatId[customMonster.MonsterType.Id];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You final goal is to not include the `GenerationMethod` tag in the XML in case the IEnumerable is empty.

So I suggest you handle exactly that, not alter the method that returns the `IEnumerable`.
`IEnumerable` is like Schrödinger's cat. It has all the items and no items at all and only when you actually enumerate, you will know exactly what items it will yield.
So returning a null, instead of the `IEnumerable` would defy the purpose of the `IEnumerable`.

So, to answer your question, create your own xml serializer ([Here is an answer on SO about how you can achieve that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17236823/can-i-provide-custom-serialization-for-xmlserializer-without-implementing-ixmlse), or simply look it up. It should be pretty straight forward). All you need to do is to change the way the `IEnumerable` is written to the XML.
The logic should be pretty straight forward:

1. Call the `.ToList()` extension method on your `IEnumerable` to enumerate it.
2. If the list has items, create the tag and add the tags in the regular way.
3. Do nothing if the list is empty.

I hope it gives you the direction you are looking for.